PYSimpleGUI License window does not open in Ubuntu
When using the sample code on the terminal with 'python PYGtest.py':
import PySimpleGUI as sg
layout = [ [sg.Text('Hello, world!')] ]
window = sg.Window('Hello Example', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
window.close()

The license window does not show in Ubuntu. As I have a developer key, I need the license window.
The icon on the left side whows but no window.
I can close the icon with right click and close,
Screenshot Ubuntu
Screenshot
RSA and tk are installed.

rsa 4.9
python 3.12.2
tk 8.6.14
pysimplegui 5.0.4

I tried different examples, same output
The license window never shows.
How do I get the window to show?
Regards
Sven

You can find the Developer Keys in the Home Window License Key tab.
The Home Window can be reached numerous ways:

run psghome,
run psghmain, or
call sg.main().



Hi Jason, Thank you for the quick answer, I tried all 3 methods and it is always the same effect, no window shows up, but as in the screenshot, the app shows in the side bar. There is no way to make the window to show.
